# Как разбить длинную строку на несколько?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Например в Delphi можно было делать так:

```
str: string;
string:="this
        is
        a 
        string";
```

Но в VC++ компилятор ругается.

Comment: Хоть и поздно, но в Delphi нельзя так делать ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите аналог того, что в Дельфи, попробуйте так:

```
std::string s = "this"
                "    is"
                "    a" 
                "    string";
```

Comment: @VladD, а 4 пробела перед последними 3-мя обязательны?

Comment: @ололо: Пробелы будут включены в строку, то есть конечная строка будет `"this    is    a    string"`. Если я правильно помню, это соответствует поведению Delphi: там вроде бы пробелы перед `is`, `а` и т. д. включаются в строку. Или может вам надо так:

    std::string s = "this\n"
                    "    is\n"
                    "    a\n" 
                    "    string";

?

Answer (score 1):

А какую строку хочется получить?

```
std::string s = "aaa\r\nbbb";
```

даст

```
aaa
bbb
```

или

```
std::string s = "aaa\
    bbb";
```

даст

```
aaa    bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QString a = "aaa"
        "bbb";
```

---

тип QString, но это не имеет значения.

Comment: @spirit Воу, благодарю. А это черта точно не интерпретируется в какой-нибудь управляющий символ?

Comment: насколько я понимаю она экнанирует(не знаю используют ли этот термин в windows) переход на новую строку.

Comment: @spirit, не. что то не так. строка точно как то изменилась. ида, в нете написано, что символ экранирования используется вовсе не для этого

Comment: @spirit а нафига `\`?

     QString a = "aaa"
            "bbb";

Не пойдёт?